# How to get the ClickOnce setup program to trigger installation of .NET 7 (works great for .NET 6)?

Tags: clickonce, .net-7.0

I have a .NET-based desktop application that is installed through ClickOnce. It was developed under .NET 6, but since it is impossible for a ClickOnce application to access its launch parameters (i.e. figure out what file it should open when it is launched through a double-click on an associated file), it has been updated to .NET 7.

For the .NET 6 version the ClickOnce setup program will kindly point out that it needs the .NET 6 framework if it isn't already installed and subsequently launch its installer if it can. However, for the .NET 7 version it won't point this out. Instead everything seems to work fine until the user tries to to launch the application. Then Windows will point out that .NET 7 is missing and redirect the user to a site where it might be downloaded.

How do I get the ClickOnce setup program to check for .NET 7 and, if it isn't there, point that out to the user during the installation?

I have set it up like this:

- The application's target framework is set to .NET 7.0
- The ClickOnce Target Framework is set to net7.0-windows
- The ClickOnce Deployment mode is Framework-dependent
- Prerequisites: Create setup program to install prerequisite components is checked
- Prerequisites: The prerequisites to install is set to .NET Desktop Runtime 7.0.9 (x64)
- Prerequisites: Specify install location of prerequisites is set to download from component vendor's website (have also tried to download from the same location as my application)